Telerik changing culture of a gridcolumn of type datetime
I need to convert my "datetimepicker" to hebrew.
I have the following telerikgrid that displays a table
 <TelerikGrid Data=@chevraBrr EditMode="@GridEditMode.Inline" Pageable="true" Height="500px"
             OnUpdate="@UpdateHandler" OnEdit="@EditHandler"
             OnCancel="@CancelHandler"
             Resizable="true" Sortable="true">
  <GridColumns>
 <GridColumn Field=@nameof(BRR_CHEVRA.Member_Mahas) Title="מספר חבר מה'ס" Sortable="true" Editable="false"/>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(BRR_CHEVRA.Join_Date) Title="תאריך הצטרפות" DisplayFormat="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" Sortable="true" />
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(BRR_CHEVRA.Comp_Name) Title="שם חברה" Sortable="true" />
 <GridCommandColumn>
            <GridCommandButton Command="Save" Icon="@SvgIcon.Save" ShowInEdit="true">@("שמור")</GridCommandButton>
            <GridCommandButton Command="Cancel" Icon="@SvgIcon.Cancel" ShowInEdit="true">@("בטל")</GridCommandButton>

            <HeaderTemplate>
                <GridCommandButton Command="Edit" Icon="@SvgIcon.Pencil">@("ערוך")</GridCommandButton>
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </GridCommandColumn>
    </GridColumns>
</TelerikGrid> 

one of the column is of type datetime
<GridColumn Field=@nameof(BRR_CHEVRA.Join_Date) Title="תאריך הצטרפות" DisplayFormat="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" Sortable="true" />

Ive been looking in google aswell as telerik's documentation obviously, but I couldnt find out how to make my datepicker display months and days in hebrew.
Can anyone provide me with a guide / a working code ( even to a different language)  so I can use it as a guide?
Ive been trying for hours to do that but couldnt.
even tried a different approach with jquery, and was trying to do:
$(function () {
    // Select input elements with type="date" and initialize the datepicker
    $('input[type="date"]').datepicker({
        // Configure datepicker options for Hebrew localization
        closeText: 'סגור',
        prevText: '&#x3c;הקודם',
        nextText: 'הבא&#x3e;',
        currentText: 'היום',
        monthNames: ['ינואר', 'פברואר', 'מרץ', 'אפריל', 'מאי', 'יוני',
            'יולי', 'אוגוסט', 'ספטמבר', 'אוקטובר', 'נובמבר', 'דצמבר'],
        monthNamesShort: ['ינו', 'פבר', 'מרץ', 'אפר', 'מאי', 'יוני',
            'יולי', 'אוג', 'ספט', 'אוק', 'נוב', 'דצמ'],
        dayNames: ['ראשון', 'שני', 'שלישי', 'רביעי', 'חמישי', 'שישי', 'שבת'],
        dayNamesShort: ['א\'', 'ב\'', 'ג\'', 'ד\'', 'ה\'', 'ו\'', 'שבת'],
        dayNamesMin: ['א\'', 'ב\'', 'ג\'', 'ד\'', 'ה\'', 'ו\'', 'שבת'],
        weekHeader: 'Wk',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 0,
        isRTL: true,
        showMonthAfterYear: true,
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: "-30:+30",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        yearSuffix: '',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            // Optional onClose function
        }
    });
});

and then in my razor page:

obviously Id get a datepicker, but it wont be translated to hebrew.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.
